# How to bundle dynamic file path in webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, sequelize.js

I'm using nodejs to write my application (server side) and to bundle all my files into single file (server.js) i'm using webpack.

the problem is when I try to run:

```
    fs.readdirSync('.')
      .filter((file) => (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== "index.js"))
      .forEach((file) => {
          console.log('file', file);

            // this is point to dist..... path.join(__dirname, file)

            var model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
            db[model.name] = model;
        });
```

The problem is it run in `dist` folder and the webpack has no files at all, just one file (server.js)..

Comment: why do you bundle your server-side code?

Comment: Webpack doesn't support dynamic bundling so you'll have to implement that code with static imports if you want to bundle. But like Adam said... why bother?